# Casting videos using Media Player Library while adhering to design requirements

Tags: javascript, chromecast

How does Media Player Library work with the design checklist requirements? I tried to style a custom receiver app that uses the media player library using divs and video tag but have had no luck because media player library doesn't seem to be understanding the different states. Any example on how to do this? I tried using this https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Media-Player-Library-Sample/ but it does not seem to apply to Media Player Library. Any other good tutorials? I understand the styled media receiver given by google uses media player library, is the source code for this out?

Comment: The project that you had mentioned does use the MPL, so I am not sure what you mean by saying it doesn't apply to MPL.

Comment: I am sorry I meant this sample with fully complaint UX guidelines https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample

Comment: We are working on enhancing that sample to include MPL as well, but meanwhile you can look at the other project to familiarize yourself with MPL.

Comment: Thank you! Any time frame on when this will be out?

Comment: It is on our list but don't have an exact time frame for it.